# How do I create an admin role with Factory girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

Ok so i want to test out features that need an admin user and i am trying to login as admin but in order to do that i need to have an admin user

here is my code

```
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:admin_role) { FactoryGirl.create(:role) }

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name "John"
    last_name  "Doe"
    email  "john@doe.com"
  end

  factory :role do
    name "Admin"
  end
end
```

how do i connect them I tried  `user.roles << user_role` but got this error

```
/Users/matt/Sites/application/spec/controllers/directory_controller_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `user' for #<Class:0x007fa550890d80> (NameError)
```

Here is my models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :roles, :through => :role_users
    has_many :role_users
    ...

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, :through => :role_users
    has_many :role_users
    ...

class RoleUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :role
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 8):

`spec/factories/user.rb`

```ruby
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name "John"
    last_name  "Doe"
    email "john@doe.com"
  end

  factory :admin_user, :parent => :user do
    roles { [ FactoryGirl.create(:admin_role) ] }
  end

  factory :role do
    name { "Role_#{rand(9999)}" }
  end

  factory :admin_role, :parent => :role do
    name "Admin"
  end
end
```

Comment: how would you use this in the describe

Comment: Are you looking for the anwser

    FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user)

Comment: undefined method `role=' for #<User:0x007ff90e203f78>

Comment: updating my question with more details of what i did

Comment: My bad, I should have used the many to many association.  I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
Factory.sequence(:email) {|n| "person#{n}@example.com" }

Factory.define :role do |r|
  r.name {"Admin"}
end

Factory.define :role_user do |ru|
  ru.association(:role)
  ru.association(:user)
end

Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.first_name {"matt"}
  u.last_name {"jones"}
  u.email {Factory.next(:email)}
end
```

and using it like

```
  let(:role_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:role_user)  }
  before { sign_in(role_user) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem, with code like:

```
describe "..." do
  let(:user) { create :user }
  let(:manager) { create :manager_role }
  user.roles << manager

  it "should ...." do
    # etc.
  end

end

# run rspec...
# => `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `user' for #<Class:0x000001016a2dc0> (NameError)
```

When I moved the `user.roles << manager` code into a `before(:each)` block, the errors disappeared. Thus, something like:

```
describe "..." do
  let(:user) { create :user }
  let(:manager) { create :manager_role }

  before(:each) do
    user.roles << manager
  end

  it "should ...." do
    # etc.
  end

end
```

This saves the pain of having to specify the `role <-> user` association in your factories.

I'm not familiar enough with how rspec and factory_girl work to understand why you can't have code like `user.roles << role` immediately after calling `let(:user) { create :user }`, but putting it into a `before(:each)` block or into an individual `it "should ... " do` block should do the trick.